# How to call R Script file from RCaller java?

Tags: java, r, rcaller

My project has some `R` files prebuilt and I need to invoke them from `Java layer`.

I cannot figure out a way to provide `RScript` file path to `RCaller`.

Need help to call `RScript` file from `RCaller Java`.

Comment: did you follow the blog posts in http://stdioe.blogspot.com.tr/search/label/rcaller ?

Answer (score 1):

The script engine is planned for **RCaller 3.0**: http://mhsatman.com/rcallerscriptengine-a-scripting-interface-for-r-in-java-using-rcaller/

Comment: Yes, it is true but the script engine will use RCaller Online in its background and path to R executable must be set before creating the engine.

Comment: Do you happen to know by when we may expect release 3.0?

Comment: Since we have many decided features and code enhancements on the new version, we are working hard to prepare a reliable and modern library to satisfy needs of the Java community. As the key feature of RCaller is simplicity, we are also working to keep it as simple as we can. The excepted date is 15th May but it can be sooner. @Paul

Comment: Thank you a lot Paul and let me congratulate you on RCaller, it is a great tool! I also like the concept of simplicity very much.

Comment: The script engine and the other new features are available now in version 3.0 : http://mhsatman.com/rcaller-3-0

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Linux`, the path for `RScript` is `/usr/bin/Rscript`.
In `Windows`, it depends on the version of `R`, but you can find its location using the file browser and it follows a pattern similar to `C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.0.2\\bin\\Rscript.exe` in a standard installation.

Addition to this, after detecting the path you can set it using

```
caller.setRscriptExecutable(pathToRscript);
```

if you want to get only one result per run and you can set the R location using

```
caller.setRExecutable(pathToR);
```

for online calculations, that is, if you perform calculations sequentially in a send-eval-get loop.

If you want your code to find out the path automatically, you can perform a recursive find for `RScript` and `R executables`. In an other way, using a `FileDialog GUI` object, you can let the user find himself.

Answer (score 0):

Now there are few other ways to call R Script from RCaller.
After setting the Rscript Executable path.
Using your RCode object(code) simply add code as-

```
code.addRCode("source('yourRscript.R')");
```

Or, you can directly call youRscript by the method

```
code.R_source("pathtoyouRscript");
```

then run your code from RCaller object using `runOnly()` command.